# Is PIE "*wank-" the ultimate root of E "wankle"?

Tags: sound-change, proto-indo-european, roots

> [***wankle***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wankle#English)
>
> From Middle English wankel, from Old English wancol (“unstable, unsteady, tottering, vacillating, weak”), from Proto-Germanic ***wankulaz** (“unsteady, wavering”), from Proto-Indo-European ***wank-, *wak-, *wek-, *weg-** (“to be unsteady; crooked”). Cognate with Dutch wankel (“shaky, unstable”), Middle High German wankel (“unsteady”), German wanken (“to waver, totter”). See also wonky.
>
> [***wonky***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wonky#English)
>
> From English dialectal wanky, alteration of Middle English wankel (“unstable, shaky”), from Old English wancol (“unstable”), from Proto-Germanic *wankulaz (“swaying, shaky, unstable”), from Proto-Germanic ***wankōnan** (“to sway, be unsteady”), from Proto-Indo-European ***wa(n)k-, *wek-, *wag-, *weg-** (“to swing, be unsteady, slant, be crooked”). Cognate with Scots wankle (“wonky”), Dutch wankel (“shaky”), German Wankelmut (“fickleness, inconstancy, vacillation”), Danish vanke (“to wander”). See also wankle.

Or there may be a PIE root **wang-*, which corresponds to the sound law PIE "G" becomes Gmc "K" in Grimm's law, rather than the PIE **wank-*?

Comment: As is, the question can't be easily answered because you don't give us non-Germanic cognates. Although Kluge argues that German *wanken* is (could be?) related to Latin vacillare, de Vaan says that Latin vacillare has no good etymology; Ernout and Meillet are of the same opinion, cf. "d'origine obscure".

Comment: The origin of Latin *vagus* is also not entirely clear, cf. de Vaan PIE *Huogo?, Ernout and Meillet "sans etymologie precise".